# How can I programmatically set a source folder in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to create small files to save basic information. I can't read and write from the files once my project is exported as a JAR, so I created a folder to store the files outside of the src folder. This only works if I set the external folder to be a source folder.

This is the code where I create the folder

```
File f = new File("Characters");

try{
    if(f.mkdir()) { 
        System.out.println("Directory created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory not created");
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I programmatically set this folder to be a source folder?

I hope this is specific enough.

Comment: What is the purpose of these files and the nature of the "basic information"?

Comment: To save settings for an object, currently just: name, red, green, and blue. I have a method to read the file and then set the name and color for each object.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have a fixed directory configurable somewhere where you can create directory and save your files there?

Comment: @BillyB.Badd Not a direct answer to your question, but you can find some relevant info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467362/reading-a-file-from-a-jar-or-anywhere-on-the-classpath?rq=1 as far as read-only access goes (contains info about where you can put files and how you can load them from your JAR).

Comment: @JasonC Cool, thanks. I can't try it out now, but I will tomorrow.

Comment: You could try to modify the `.classpath` file to add such kind of entry: `<classpathentry kind="src" path="YOUR_FOLDER"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sound more like resource files rather then source files which require compiling.

Why not put them in a resource directory and load them when needed?